# Update recordset without updating database

Tags: excel, vba, recordset

I use an ADODB connection to connect to my Access DB in Excel VBA and get the records with a recordset. I want to update the recordset, but when i update the recordset i also update the table in the DB. Is it possible to update the recordset but not the db? Here is my code,

```
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\jasons\Documents\UPD.accdb"
rs.Open "SELECT ITEM, SL AS SL FROM Table2", con, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic

rs.MoveFirst
  Do
        rs.Update "SL", 250
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop Until rs.EOF

con.Close
Set con = Nothing
```

Comment: It is possible, you are looking for "Disconnected Recordsets" , check http://www.devguru.com/features/tutorials/DisconnectedRecordsets/tutDisconnRS

Comment: Thanks pony2deer that worked perfectly. I will post my code as an answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the link by pony2deer i adjusted my code only by adding

```
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
```

Here is the full code,

```
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
sql = "SELECT * FROM Table2"

con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\jasons\Documents\UPD.accdb"
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
rs.Open sql, con

Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
con.Close

rs.MoveFirst
  Do
        rs.Update "SL", 20
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop Until rs.EOF
```